# Create groups in svn

Tags: security, svn

I have a svn repository, but I want to control the access, For example one of the group have access for `test` folder but don't have access for the `test2` folder. It's possible this, or I have to create different repository if I want to reach this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you set up permissions and ACLs in a SVN repository depends on the way this repository is accessed.
You can apply restrictions to each folder in a repository only with the first two methods.

- If it is served via HTTP/HTTPS then it works like it is a DAV directory and the configuration is done via Apache configuration files.
- If it is served via plain svnserve daemon then you must use its own configuration file.
- If it is svnserve incapsulated in SSH then the usual filesystem permissions apply, so you must set up different repositories if you want to give different rights to different groups on different directories of the repo.

A full answer here would be too long and ineffective. So I invite you to read the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), especially the chapter 6: server configuration.